# Do I really need to accommodate both GET and POST request formats in a django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to django but something I don't understand is the need for accommodating both the GET and POST request types when developing a form. Please refer to code below from django docs:

```
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

The reason this confuses me is because I have developed a GET based form and it is working and I have no need for the POST portion above? See below:

```
# views.py
def simplifier_form(request):
    form = LabelForm()
    return render(request, "simplifier.html", {"form": form})

def process_simplifier(request):
    label_name = request.GET.get('labels')
    results = Disturbance.objects.filter(labeldisturbances__label_name=label_name)
    painsresults = Pain.objects.filter(disturbances__pk__in=results).distinct()
    total_disturbances = Disturbance.objects.filter(pain__pk__in=painsresults)
    total_labels = Label.objects.filter(disturbances__pk__in=total_disturbances).distinct()
    context = {'results': results, 'painsresults': painsresults, 'total_disturbances': total_disturbances, 'total_labels': total_labels}
    return render(request,'process_simplifier.html', context)

# forms.py
class LabelForm(ModelForm):
    labels = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Label.objects.all(),
    to_field_name='label_name',
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'labels'}),
    )

    class Meta:   
        model = Label
        fields = ['labels']
```

So why do the django docs and most examples include code for both methods when you only really use one like in my example above?

Answer (score 0):

The question is... How do you want to process your from when submitted on POST?

Remember, your form can also be submitted on GET... You can decide what you would want to do if submitted on GET.